# startActivityForResult not called with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin

I have three activities A, B and C. Suppose A starts B and B starts C with `startsActivity()`.

Stack becomes A, B, C.

Now suppose, C makes B to come to front by using `startActivityForResult()` and passing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Stack becomes A, C, B.

In B, I have written this code:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_DESTROY_C)
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

I am expecting that C's `onActivityResult()` would be called after back button on B is pressed. But it is not getting called. Why? Please help.

Please note that this is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185868/flag-activity-reorder-to-front-and-startactivityforresult) question. Scenario of my question is different.

Comment: Why on back press of B will call onActivityResult for C? Since A -> B -> C, C's back press will call B, right? share how you are starting Activity B and C and their on back press?

Comment: I used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT ` when C starts B with `startActivityForResult()`. So stack becomes: A, C, B. That's why I am expecting `onActivityResult()` of C to be called.